# GUIDs need replacing every time I press F5 - any way around this?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

(Caveat: this is the first time I've ever worked with SharePoint, so am probably failing to understand something fairly fundamental. But Google's been singularly unhelpful, so here I am.)

I'm creating some custom fields to use in a custom content type (roughly following [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx)). As this is the first time I've done this, my usual method of hitting F5 every so often to check everything is still working is failing, because every time I do I get complaints about Id collisions. If I replace the Ids of all the fields that were present the last time I it F5, everything works, but this seems like far too much effort.

Is there some way of running what I've got without having to replace all the GUIDs every time? It seems far too long-winded.

I'm on VS2010.

Thanks!

Comment: At the bottom of the article there are several comments and links about people with similar issues.

Comment: Try: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2022443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging:

This is a known issue to do with VS (I think) not properly retracting projects. Try manually retracting (right click on the project), or restarting VS seems to fix it too. Interestingly, this issue seemed to resolve itself as soon as I finished adding the fields to content types.

If anyone has any more insights on this, I'd love to hear them!